# Unable to upload CSV file using Python/Django

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to upload the csv file using Django and planning to parse the CSV file. But this code fails to upload the file and keeps going to the else condition. What is wrong with this code? Thanks!

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

import csv
import codecs

from items.models import UploadFileForm


def handle_files(f):
    reader = csv.DictReader(open(f))
    for row in reader:
    print row

def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_files(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/workflow/')
        else:
            print form.errors
            print request.FILES
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/workflow/upload')

    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'formset': form})
```

template.html

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

   <input type="file" name="csv_file" />
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

</form>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

Comment: Indentation is correct? At some places u have used 2 spaces and 4 on others!

Comment: which else condition ? there are 2 in your listing. Also show us your html form for the submission.

Comment: @AbijithMg I have fixed the indentation, it was a typo while typing in stackoverflow

Comment: @gipsy It is the else condition associated with form.is_valid()

Comment: do you have ```enctype='multipart/form-data'``` in your form element?

Comment: Can you show us the form.errors value?

Comment: @Abhijith Mg 
`<ul class="errorlist"><li>file<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
<MultiValueDict: {u'csv_file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: test_application_data - Sheet 1.csv (application/vnd.ms-excel)>]}>`

Comment: @gipsy Yes I do. I have updated the description with my template as well

Comment: what's the output of print form.errors?

Comment: @gipsy This was the output

`<ul class="errorlist"><li>file<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul> <MultiValueDict: {u'csv_file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: test_application_data - Sheet 1.csv (application/vnd.ms-excel)>]}>`

Comment: show us the code for UploadFileForm as well

Comment: Sure.  I have added it as well

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can try(You don't need to check whether form is valid unless u have validation enabled):

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.FILES:
            handle_files(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/workflow/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/workflow/upload')

    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'formset': form})
```